# How to automate SFTP file drop with password

Tags: sftp, filemaker

I am dropping off a file on a server on a weekly basis. The destination server can only authenticate via password, not public key. Is there a feature in filemaker that would allow me to authenticate via a password stored locally instead of via key authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing native, but a few suggestions on a workaround:

1  Use plugins

2  Use AppleScript from FileMaker to call curl (on a mac)

3  Use AppleScrip to call bash and use ftp

4  Use VBScript on Windows, with wget or curl for Windows

5  Use cmd to invoke ftp on Windows

Comment: Thanks. If we have terminal access then we can use lftp installed from homebrew.